# How to store HDFS output to MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, mapreduce, hdfs

I have used Pig and Hive for MapReduce operations on a dataset which is stored in HDFS. Now I want to transfer that output to store it into MySQL table.

How can I transfer the output to MySQL?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage [`Apache Sqoop`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html) to export from `HDFS` to `MySQL`.

**Illustration:**

**This is the data in HDFS**

```
# hadoop fs -ls /example_hive  
/example_hive/file1.csv


# hadoop fs -cat /example_hive/*
1,foo
2,bar
3,ack
4,irk
5,pqr
```

**Create the target table in MySQL `test` database**

```
> create table test.example_mysql(h1 int, h2 varchar(100));
```

**Export using Sqoop command.** *(Update values for parameters --connect, --username, --password as per your environment)*

```
# sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" --username "root" --password hadoop --table "example_mysql" --export-dir "hdfs:///example_hive" --input-fields-terminated-by ','
```

**Check data in MySQL**

```
> select * from test.example_mysql;
+------+------+
| h1   | h2   |
+------+------+
|    1 | foo  |
|    2 | bar  |
|    3 | ack  |
|    4 | irk  |
|    5 | pqr  |
+------+------+
```